# How to install python3.7-dev on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, python-3.7, ubuntu-20.04

I need to use Python3.7 for a project, but Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have python3.7-dev in the apt repositories. I've installed Python3.7 from a tarball, but it doesn't install the headers. I noticed in the build directory that `libpython3.7m.a` exists, but I'm looking for `libpython3.7.so`. I don't see any options to build shared versus static library, and I don't where that file goes, I was hoping the build script would take care of that.

**Does anyone know the recommended way to install python headers from older versions?**

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

You can install it for any version of python. by `sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Try this once and let me know if it didn't solve

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: No this doesn't work, because the version in the Ubuntu 20.04 repos is 3.8, but I need 3.7.

Comment: So, you need a specific version. I found one site that says to try with 'sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev'  Let me know if this worked. I will edit the answer if it worked correctly which can help others who is having the same issue. Check this site: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/python3.7-dev

Comment: Yeap `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev` did the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with pyenv?

Comment: @Jimi it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use `libpython3.7m-pic.a` instead, which acts like `libpython3.7.so` to some extent